# How to check whether a memmoryview in Null in cython

Tags: null, cython, memoryview, typed-memory-views

I want to check whether a memory view is initialized with None.
I have a function like this:

```
cdef void test(int[:] a):
    if a == NULL:
        print("invalid data")

cdef int[:] memview = None
test(memview)
```

I get this error when I compile this:

```
Invalid types for '==' (int[:], void *)
```

Is the problem assigning None to the memmory view? If that's not the case, what can I do to detect the NULL values?

Thanks!

Comment: `None` is a Python object and `NULL` is an empty C pointer. They aren't the same thing

Comment: That's not the main point. The main problem is memmoryview and null are not comparable. How can we check whether memmoryview is null?

Comment: I think you missed the point I was trying to hint at: the memoryview is never `NULL`. It might be `None`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!
I was using it inside a nogil function that's why I thought it can not be a python object. Isn't none a python thing? If so, Why can I compare it to a memoryview inside a nogil scope?

Comment: I'm actually a little surprised it works in a `nogil` block. However, comparing to `None` shouldn't require any reference counting and will end up as a simple pointer comparison in C, so should be possible without the GIL I think.

Comment: Thanks! This has been really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comments into a very answer:

You are assigning `None` to your memoryview:

```
cdef int[:] memview = None
```

Therefore it makes sense to check it against `None`, not against `NULL`:

```
if a is None:
```

Ultimately they're similar concepts but different things: `NULL` is a pointer that doesn't point to anything, while `None` is a singleton Python object that indicates that something is unset. The distinction is really between C level and Python level and here memoryviews act "Python level".

---

There's an additional detail that lets you do `if a is None` inside a `nogil` block: Python ensures that there is exactly one `None` object in existence (and also that it remains the same `None` object for the entire program). Therefore it's possible to translate `a is None` to the C code

```
((PyObject *) __pyx_v_a.memview) == Py_None
```

i.e. a simple pointer comparison, that doesn't need the GIL since there's no changes to reference counts.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer.
Are memmoryviews python objects? They can be used inside nogil and we need to define them with cdef so my guess is they are C  level.
If that's the case, how is it that they can be None? I thought that this None would be translated to C Null but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: They aren't Python objects. What they can do is wrap a Python object that exports the Python buffer interface. So the test is really "is the wrapped object set to `None`?" Really it's a pretty arbitrary decision whether to represent that by `None` or `NULL`.

Comment: I tried this, but I got the following error when I changed `if sample_weight != NULL:` to the following: `if ((PyObject *) __pyx_v_sample_weight.memview) != Py_None:`. I then get an error stating  

```if ((PyObject *) __pyx_v_sample_weight.memview) != Py_None:
                            ^
Expected an identifier or literal
```. Any idea what to do here?

Comment: The C code is what Cython generates, not what you write yourself.